Transfer Learning: Image classification High accuracy but very high val_loss. Why?
I'm using tensorflow and Keras to do transfer learning using Resnet_50. The issue I am having is that my model seems to be doing good on accuracy but my val_loss is extremely high as well as when i try to make predictitions the accuracy is very low.
Here are the relevent parts of code:
# Create an ImageDataGenerator with data augmentation for training
data_generator = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    validation_split=0.5,
    rotation_range=30,  # Random rotations
    width_shift_range=0.2,  # Horizontal shifts
    height_shift_range=0.2,  # Vertical shifts
    shear_range=0.2,  # Shear transformations
    zoom_range=0.2,  # Zoom
    horizontal_flip=True,  # Horizontal flips
)

# Load and preprocess training data
train_data_flow = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    dataset_path,
    target_size=(224, 224),  # Resize images to 224x224
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training'  # Use training subset
)

# Load and preprocess validation data
val_data_flow = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    dataset_path,
    target_size=(224, 224),  # Resize images to 224x224
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation'  # Use validation subset
)

Loading The Model
# Load the model from TensorFlow Hub
model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/resnet_50/feature_vector/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_url, input_shape=(224, 224, 3) , trainable=False)

# Create a Sequential model with dropout and batch normalization
model = keras.Sequential([
    hub_layer,
    layers.Dropout(0.2),  # Lower dropout rate
    layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),  # Batch normalization
    layers.Dropout(0.5),  # Dropout
    layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')
])

# Build the Sequential model
model.build((None, 224, 224, 3))

# Summary of the model
model.summary()

I then compile :
# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

And Finally :
# Fit the model with early stopping
history = model.fit(
    train_data_flow,
    validation_data=val_data_flow,
    epochs=15,  # Number of epochs,
)

Here are the epochs:
Epoch 1/15
81/81 [==============================] - 489s 6s/step - loss: 0.3773 - accuracy: 0.8832 - val_loss: 0.7994 - val_accuracy: 0.7476
Epoch 2/15
81/81 [==============================] - 489s 6s/step - loss: 0.3316 - accuracy: 0.8980 - val_loss: 0.8229 - val_accuracy: 0.7378
Epoch 3/15
81/81 [==============================] - 488s 6s/step - loss: 0.3468 - accuracy: 0.8879 - val_loss: 0.8221 - val_accuracy: 0.7362
Epoch 4/15
81/81 [==============================] - 489s 6s/step - loss: 0.3148 - accuracy: 0.9011 - val_loss: 0.8380 - val_accuracy: 0.7362
Epoch 5/15
81/81 [==============================] - 488s 6s/step - loss: 0.3250 - accuracy: 0.8972 - val_loss: 0.7680 - val_accuracy: 0.7409
Epoch 6/15
81/81 [==============================] - 491s 6s/step - loss: 0.3100 - accuracy: 0.9026 - val_loss: 0.7220 - val_accuracy: 0.7616
Epoch 7/15
81/81 [==============================] - 491s 6s/step - loss: 0.2844 - accuracy: 0.9120 - val_loss: 0.7259 - val_accuracy: 0.7651
Epoch 8/15
81/81 [==============================] - 490s 6s/step - loss: 0.2811 - accuracy: 0.9007 - val_loss: 0.7722 - val_accuracy: 0.7511
Epoch 9/15
81/81 [==============================] - 490s 6s/step - loss: 0.2689 - accuracy: 0.9167 - val_loss: 0.7943 - val_accuracy: 0.7433
Epoch 10/15
81/81 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2569 - accuracy: 0.9182

Predicting:
Model Accuracy on Test Set: 0.2021069059695669


It is very difficult to point to a single thing as an issue with the code without knowing more about the training, validation and testing data sets.
I would say, though, that it looks like you have overfitting in your model by epoch 8. This can be seen by looking at the val_loss and val_accuracy parameters. You should expect that validation loss decreases over the complete training loop while validation accuracy increases. Once you see that either is moving in the opposite direction you might have overfitting. This would also explain some (if not all) of your poor performance on the test set.
One possible solution to this is to just stop fitting the model once you hit overfitting, for example try setting the epoch parameter to something lower than 15, maybe: epochs=8.
Another solution could be to set a different learning rate with a specified optimizer, see this answer for a more thourough explanation on this topic.

Thanks For the help I'm trying with epochs = 8 right now , as well as I've modified the learning rate to see if there's an improvement

You are getting overfitted. You could think of overfitting as if the model is so expressive that is learning by heart all the training dataset, and not really learning the patterns of the images.
An example I like is when you have little time to study for a test. What do you do here? Well, you learn by heart all the previous tests. You will do good if they ask you something similar to that, but if they ask you something different you will do horrible.
So, how can you tell when you are overfitted? You get really good results in the training dataset but catastrophic results in the validation.
Now the important part, how to not overfit? Well, a lot of options here. For starter, you could try changing the model to a smaller one, to one with fewer parameters. You could change data augmentation on your data (although it seems okay, but in some cases one data augmentation might kill the model. I would add them one by one and check see if they improve the result or not. For this you could train on only a sample dataset so it doesn't take that long). You could increase the dropout or use less fewer neurones in the penultimate layer, try 128 for example. Lastly, you could try early stopping
With the 128 neurones I mean instead of this right here that you have:
    model = keras.Sequential([
    hub_layer,
    layers.Dropout(0.2),  # Lower dropout rate
    layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),  # Batch normalization
    layers.Dropout(0.5),  # Dropout
    layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')
])

Try out something like this:
    model = keras.Sequential([
    hub_layer,
    layers.Dropout(0.2),  
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'), # see the decrease in parameters
    layers.BatchNormalization(),  
    layers.Dropout(0.5),  # Dropout
    layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')
])

I believe with something like this and early stopping it should do. I really recommend you checking out the Keras Callbacks, they have a lot of useful stuff like the EarlyStopping or ReduceLROnPlateau

Thanks , I am aware of overfitting but im new to keras. I thought i had added data augmentation in the first code snippet. What do you mean by 156? Also I had a question , Hope you don't mind, could something called data preprocessing be causing the issue? I dont quite fully grasps what that means but I've seen it pop up a few times

I'm sorry, I am editing my answer with those errors fixed (you are clearly doing data augmentation my bad)

I mean, sometimes preprocessing the data wrongly can cause chaos if an important feature is lost. For example, I did a project of medical images where the resolution was extremely importan. I was reducing the size way to much and so the high resolution was lost. Once i started working with the original size images it improved like a 50%.

im currently 3 epochs in and this is how it's looking with a learning rate of 0.01:
loss: 1.0081 - accuracy: 0.6947 - val_loss: 0.9015 - val_accuracy: 0.7374
 loss: 0.5489 - accuracy: 0.8349 - val_loss: 0.8593 - val_accuracy: 0.7304
loss: 0.4689 - accuracy: 0.8618 - val_loss: 0.7618 - val_accuracy: 0.7597
The thing is with res_net my input has to be 224 x 224 while my original dataset images are around 900x900.

It looks better, but in my opinion the gap in epoch 3 is still to big yet, and train acc is rising fast. I'd try to reduce the first dense layer even further, or completely omit it. You could also increase the dropout value from 0.2 to 04 or 0.5. Or, switch the resnet50 backbone to a smaller one. If the backbone is too big, one can only do so much against overfitting.

I running it again without the data augmentation. ill put the results in a few. Il try it with the increased dropout rate as well after that. Thanks!

Without data augmentation It seems to run bettter here are the first few epochs:
loss: 0.8504 - accuracy: 0.7582 - val_loss: 0.6676 - val_accuracy: 0.7940
2nd
loss: 0.3810 - accuracy: 0.8847 - val_loss: 0.6466 - val_accuracy: 0.8041
3rd
loss: 0.2906 - accuracy: 0.9159 - val_loss: 0.6164 - val_accuracy: 0.8080
My question is how low should val_loss be? does the val accuracy need to be as close as possible to the accuracy?

The val loss should be close to the train loss. I can't give you a number since it will depend on the loss and the problem. A good way to check if it's getting overfitted is to see when the val loss starts diverging from the train loss. So, I wouldn't mind the starting value of the difference between the losses, but they should maintain more or less that difference. In this case, your train loss is decreasing but your val loss maintains always the same, so you are getting overfitted. You can plot the losses and compare to how it should look, there are plenty of images

Epoch 1/8
loss: 0.9002 - accuracy: 0.7266 - val_loss: 0.8100 - val_accuracy: 0.7702
Epoch 2/8
loss: 0.4307 - accuracy: 0.8766 - val_loss: 0.5907 - val_accuracy: 0.7987
Epoch 3/8
loss: 0.3254 - accuracy: 0.9030 - val_loss: 0.6382 - val_accuracy: 0.8010
Epoch 4/8
loss: 0.2736 - accuracy: 0.9245 - val_loss: 0.5845 - val_accuracy: 0.8162
Here are the results. Not great
Biggest issue is predictions:
Model Accuracy on Test Set: 0.184939523995318

Yeah you are still getting overfitted. Check how the train loss is decreasing and the val loss is stucked in ~0.6. Decrease the model size or increase dropout/other regularization techniques.

By decrease the model size you mean use another pre trained model? I will try tweaking and running to see what works best. Thanks for all the help @Federico

Yes! You can try other options of CNN with fewer parameters. You can also remove the "head" that you are adding to the model and just leave one last layer of 9 neurons for the classification
